# Is it possible to find min/max of a number in x86 without using shifts or xor?

Tags: c, x86

I'm trying to write min/max functions in x86. I've been able to do this with the use of shifts and with the use of xor, but I need to find a way to write it without these uses. Can someone lead me in the right direction for this?

Comment: `>` , `<` , `if` statements, and some variables?

Comment: Why would you need shifts and xor to find min and max and why x86 has anything to do with it?

Comment: Can't you use `CMOV`? Or just code the `min` function in C and compile it with `gcc -mtune=native -O2 -fverbose-asm -S` ...

Answer (score 0):

Example max function:

```
int max(int *arr,int n){
    int max=arr[0];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)max=(arr[i]>max)?arr[i]:max;
    return max;
    }
```

This will take an array of integers (`arr`) and it's size (`n`) as argument and return the maximum value containing in the array.

To find min change `max=(arr[i]>max)?arr[i]:max;` to `max=(arr[i]<max)?arr[i]:max;`

Comment: It's a good solution but for loops inherently involve jumps which I can't use. Apparently there is a branch prediction solution to this but I can't seem to figure this out

Comment: So its for a homework after all... well you can't deal with arrays without loops. If you really can't use loops, you can use recursion.

Comment: Now if you are just comparing two numbers, a simple `max = (a > b ? a : b)` will do.